# Why I get an error message "Notice: Undefined index: formats ..." in php?

Tags: php

When I run my PHP code, it gives an error message "`Notice: Undefined index: formats in C:\xampp\htdocs\playit2\scripts\session.php on line 39`".

**Here is my HTML code.**

```
$my_items = array();

$jsql_e = mysql_query("select request_list.id, request_list.formats, request_list.product_id, request_list.sent_on, request_list.return_on, products.name, products.certificate from request_list, products where request_list.email='$visit_email' and request_list.sent='1' and request_list.returned='1' and products.id=request_list.product_id") or die(mysql_error());

$jarr_rent_list_history = array();

while($jfet_e = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsql_e)){
    $jfet_e = array_filter($jfet_e);
    if(count($jfet_e) > 0){ array_push($jarr_rent_list_history, $jfet_e); }
}

foreach($jarr_rent_list_requested as $item_arr){
    if((count($item_arr) > 0) && (strlen($item_arr['product_id']) > 0)){
        array_push($my_items, $item_arr['product_id'], $item_arr['formats']);
    }
}
```

The error gives at "`if((count($item_arr) > 0) && (strlen($item_arr['product_id']) > 0)){`" and "formats" is an id type.

Comment: The error is self explanatory... the index 'formats' does not exist in `$item_arr`. Try `print_r()` on the `$item_arr` to see in which iteration it is non-existent...

Comment: `$item_arr['formats']` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your question is incorrect. If you have the `Notice: Undefined index: formats in C:\xampp\htdocs\playit2\scripts\session.php on line 39` error. My guess is that its about the line `array_push($my_items, $item_arr['product_id'], $item_arr['formats'])`.

The answer itself is pretty much the error you are getting. The key `formats` does not exist in the array `$item_arr`.

It is best to check this by doing for example:

`array_push($my_items, $item_arr['product_id'],  ( isset($item_arr['formats']) ? $item_arr['formats'] : null)`

This way the formats value will be set to `null` if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined index means **EXACTLY** what it says.

`$item_arr['formats']` is not defined. You should check if it is before using it.

This **may** work depending on your situation. Can you deal with `formats` being empty?

```
$item_arr['formats'] = (isset($item_arr['formats']))?$item_arr['formats']:"";
```